# Navbar-toggle linebreak colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling to amend the colour of the line break on twitter bootstrap 3 navbar-toggle function.

As you can see from this image there is a line break which is using my background colour.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgVAm.jpg

I have attempted a number of options such as;

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 background-color: #000;
}
```

and a few other suggestion from the great world wide web.. but none seem to work.

any advice would be great.

regards & many thanks.

edit 1 code;

```
<header class="clearfix">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" style="font-size: 16px;color:#04fa00"></i>

        </button>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BollinBuild</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.php">SERVICES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="testimonals.php">TESTIMONALS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.php">GALLERY</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="admin.php">ADMIN</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
            </header>
```

css

```
#container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    padding: 21px 25px 21px 25px;
    margin: 0!important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: #1c1c1c;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #04fa00;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #04fa00;
    color: #04fa00;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to help. Perhaps you can create something on bootply.com to show us what the problem is?

Comment: Hi David, I'm new to this, can I just give you link for live version? 

regards

Comment: Hi @DavidG please see amended post.

Comment: from what i can work out it is because of the container background colour, as the nav bar is in a container the line break is using that background if that makes sense?

Comment: A link to live would work too.

Comment: So you want the green bar removing, the bar that appears when you hover over a menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a border that is providing the white bar, just add this CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks this works :) 

do you know how to remove the scroll bar within the collapse?

Comment: Ask another question and you'll get another answer :)